# Is my ManyToOne relationship correct?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm experimenting my first relationship tests with Mongoose, and I would like to know if I'm doing things correclty before going further.

I have two models : a Galaxy and a StarSystem. A Galaxy has many StarSystems, and a StarSystem has one Galaxy.

Here are my models :

Galaxy :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var galaxySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    planets: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refs: 'StarSystem'
    }]
});

var Galaxy = mongoose.model('Galaxy', galaxySchema);

module.exports = Galaxy;
```

StarSystem :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var starSystemSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
       type: String,
       required: true
    },
    xPosition: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    yPosition: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    starType: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 7
    },
    galaxy: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Galaxy',
        required: true
    }
});

var StarSystem = mongoose.model('StarSystem', starSystemSchema);

module.exports = StarSystem;
```

StarSystem routes :

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var config = require('../config');
var StarSystem = require('../models/star_system');
var Galaxy = require('../models/galaxy');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    StarSystem.find().exec(function(err, starSystems) {
        res.json(starSystems);
    });
});

router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    StarSystem.findById(req.params.id, function(err, starSystem) {
        if (undefined === starSystem) {
            res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Star System not found.'
            });
        }
        else {
            res.json(starSystem);
        }
    });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var starSystem = new StarSystem(req.rawBody);

    starSystem.save(function(err, starSystem) {
        if (null != err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.status(201).json({
                location: config.app.domain + '/star-systems/' + starSystem._id
            });
        }
    });

    Galaxy.findById(req.rawBody.galaxy, function(err, galaxy) {
        galaxy.planets.push(starSystem);
        galaxy.save();
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My question is specifically about the way I handle adding a StarSystem to the Galaxy in the "POST" method. I'm currently adding it to the array, but I don't know if there is something faster/easier. I would appreciate any advices about my code.

Comment: I noticed that you did not accept or comment on my answer yet. When I was able to help you, please accept my answer. When I was not able to help you, please comment to tell me what other information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself why you have a reference from the galaxy to the star systems in the first place.

When you retrieve a `Galaxy` object, all you get about its star systems is a list of _id's. The _id's alone give your application nothing except maybe knowing how many there are. To get any useful data about the star systems you need to perform a subsequent query on the `StarSystem` collection to resolve the references.

So when you need to query the `StarSystem` collection anyway, you can do that in parallel while you are still waiting for the results from Galaxy by finding the `StarSystem`'s with `galaxy:galaxyId`.

This is not just faster, it also improves consistency (no possibility for contradictory StarSystem->Galaxy and Galaxy->StarSystem references) and most of all it prevents the Galaxy object from growing. MongoDB does not like growing objects, because whenever an object grows to twice its size, the database needs to delete it from the hard drive and append it to the end of the file which degrades write performance.

A situation where arrays of references can be useful is when you have a n:m relation. But unless you are going to simulate [galaxy collisions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrIk6dKcdoU), you won't ever have `StarSystem`s which belong to more than one `Galaxy`.